# OSB logging - Process writes logs in both osb_server1.out and log file ..?

Tags: osb

I have few OSB proxy service and we have configured few log operations for logging but while testing, I noticed logs are getting written in both osb_server1.out and osb_server1.log file. I dont want to write logs in osb_server1.out file.

I am running my weblogic server in development mode.

Could someone please advice me whats wrong I am doing here